# Excel VBA decrease runtime

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I am copying and pasting data from one workbook to another workbook. Unfortunately I am not satisfied with my runtime. Especially this part of my code needs a lot of time. Do you have any idea to decrease the runtime?

```
Function CopyData()

sws.Activate
Range("C4:GF4").Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.Copy

tws.Activate
Range("A12").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("D12:GD12").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,    SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End Function
```

Comment: How long does it take currently? Have you tried to time it? This doesn't look like it will took long. Are there other reasons?

Comment: did you try `application.calculation=xlmanual` before pasting? Do not forget to switch it back to auto afterwards. Actually you are pasting it as values but i assumed there may be other formulas in the sheet which uses these values.

Comment: Generally speaking, working with `Select` will slow down your code, as you are altering the excel sheet. A first step to prevent this from slowing down your code would be `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the beginning of the function.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your ideas. @ Dubison: I only need the values and  no formulas. @ EngJon: How would my code look like avoiding the Select? That would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should increase performance, and is what @EngJon was referring to about not using select.

```
Function CopyData()
    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sws.Activate
    Range("C4:GF" & Range("GF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    tws.Activate
    Range("A12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Set rng = Range("D12:GD" & Range("GD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.Value = rng.Value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Comment: Can you not get rid of the `Activate` as well? `sws.Range("C4:GF" & sws.Range("GF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy` and `tws.Range("A12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll`  and `Set rng = tws.Range("D12:GD" & tws.Range("GD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`?